# Outlier removal techniques from an array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, outliers

I know there's a ton resources online for outlier removal, but I haven't yet managed to obtain what I exactly want, so posting here, I have an array (or DF) of `4` columns. Now I want to remove the rows from the DF based on a column's outlier values. The following is what I have tried, but they are not perfect.

```
def outliers2(data2, m = 4.5):
    c=[]
    data = data2[:,1] # Choosing the column
    d = np.abs(data - np.median(data)) # deviation comoutation
    mdev = np.median(d) # mean deviation
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if (abs(data[i] - mdev) < m * np.std(data)):
            c.append(data2[i])            
    return c

x = pd.DataFrame(outliers2(np.array(b)))
column = ['t','orig_w','filt_w','smt_w']
x.columns = column

#Plot
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10,8]
plt.plot(b.t,b.orig_w,'o',label='Original',alpha=0.8) # Original
plt.plot(x.t,x.orig_w,'.',c='r',label='Outlier removed',alpha=0.8) # After outlier removal
plt.legend()
```

the plot illustrates how the results looks, red points after the outlier treatment over the blue original points. I would really like to get rid of those vertical group of points around the x~0 mark. What to do ?

A link to the data file is provided here : [Full data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aYPX31zE4P-LW5Hva6fdqNUf4fwYHpJa/view?usp=sharing)
[image]
The green circles show typically the points i would like to get rid of
[image]

Comment: Can you post another images encircling the outliers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [scipy's median_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.median_filter.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import median_filter

b = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

x = b.copy()
x.orig_w = median_filter(b.orig_w, size=15)

#Plot
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10,8]
#Original
plt.plot(b.t,b.orig_w,'o',label='Original',alpha=0.8) 
# After outlier removal
plt.plot(x.t,x.orig_w,'.',c='r',label='Outlier removed',alpha=0.8) 
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since your data looks sinusoidal, it probably makes sense to perform your outliers removal technique by using a sliding window. You can compute median and standard deviation in the direct neighborhood of the points you are testing and check if it's an outlier by checking if your point is within a specified number of the standard deviation from your median. This method exists under the name of `Hampel filter` (more details [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26552/what-is-a-hampel-filter-and-how-does-it-work) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/outlier-detection-with-hampel-filter-85ddf523c73d)). Below is a way to implement it with a window size equal to 50 samples on each side and a threshold based on 1.25 std:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_orig=pd.read_csv('trial_data.csv')

def hampel_filter(df_orig, m = 1.25,win=50):
  c=[]
  k = 1.4826 
  for i in range(len(df_orig)):

      med=np.median(df_orig['orig_w'][np.amax([0,i-win]):np.amin([len(df_orig['orig_w']),i+win])])
      mad=np.std(np.abs(df_orig['orig_w'][np.amax([0,i-win]):np.amin([len(df_orig['orig_w']),i+win])]-med))
      sigma=k*mad
      
      if np.abs(med-df_orig['orig_w'][i])<m*sigma:
          c.append(df_orig.loc[i])            
  return c

x = pd.DataFrame(hampel_filter(df_orig))
column = ['t','orig_w','filt_w','smt_w']
x.columns = column

#Plot
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10,8]
plt.plot(df['t'],df['orig_w'],'o',label='Original',alpha=0.8) # Original
plt.plot(x.t,x.orig_w,'.',c='r',label='Outlier removed',alpha=0.8) # After outlier removal
plt.legend()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

You can then fine tune `win` and `m` to get a result that works for you.