# How to scale a vector containing x or y axis data by a constant factor, e.g. 100 or 0.01

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I plot some data using `matplotlib`, now I want to multiply the `x_axis` by 100. My problem is that the `x_axis` is text format, what I mean is that:

```
print(x)--> Text(0.5, 0, 'time (ps)')
```

```
plt.plot(rmsd, color='blue')
x = plt.xlabel('time (ps)')
y_1 = plt.ylabel('rmsd_join (nm)')


plt.plot(np.arange(40, len(rmsd)*100, 100), rmsd, color='b')
x = plt.xlabel('time (ps)')
y_1 = plt.ylabel('RMSD_join (nm)')
```

test data for rmsd:

[0.         0.10993838 0.12384398 0.13261515 0.12955852 0.12920746
0.12922838 0.1342765  0.14746922 0.14724171 0.15128462 0.16030522
0.15995741 0.15604569 0.16712566 0.15712656 0.16754897 0.16771026
0.16590466 0.1708724  0.15938507 0.16021411 0.16368654 0.16497642
0.15517348 0.1557821  0.15674755 0.16893421 0.16883816 0.16835387
0.16886058 0.16845982 0.16266923 0.1667564  0.16850154 0.17983358
0.180383   0.18168528 0.17745751 0.1723941  0.1763786  0.18912238
0.18045492 0.17736912 0.18628192 0.18547903 0.17390871 0.18494183
0.19064023 0.18160789 0.19462068 0.185878   0.19211231 0.19208416
0.18572375 0.19119252 0.19534728 0.19491221 0.19951849 0.2061197 ]

Comment: Please share your code as text, never as image.  Could you also add some test data for `rmsd`?  If it is a 1D array, you could try `plt.plot(np.arange(0, len(rmsd)*100, 100), rmsd, color='b')`.  This would explicitly give the x-values (which is the recommended way to use `plt.plot()`). Note that the `x label` is a text, but the `x ticks` are numbers here.

Comment: Thanks, I am analyzing the trajectory file of a biological system using Mdtraj package. However, I put a try to your suggestion and it worked. for now, I have some confusion about why the plot is similar in both scenarios whether I multiplied the x_axis by 100 or not (because I think by multiplying the x_axis by 100 it should be something like smoother).

Comment: I have attached test data for rmsd, plus my previous and current codes

Comment: Why would data multiplication result in a smoother line? You amplify signal and noise similarly. Maybe you are actually looking for [a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70720254/8881141)?