# Detection of continuous change points/anomalies

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

I'm working on a time series data that has in its values some outliers/anomalies that i've been able to detect by using a change point detection algorithm.

But the problem is that sometimes it only detects the beginning and the end of the anomaly , and not all the points that are included in the interval. Do u have any idea how to do so if the list of anomalies points ( indexes and values) is provided?

i actually get this [image]

but i want for example the green circle to be detected all for anomaly : [image]

Comment: Outlier detection is often prone to errors. Your general question does not allow to provide a good answer. Please include more information on the data, what you consider outliers/anomalies, and what your current strategy (in code) is.

Comment: One way to address this problem is the use of scipy's median filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70720254/8881141